# Verifying emergency decryption code

Tags: macos, filevault

I encrypted my computer with FileVault full disk encryption on Yosemite. FileVault gave me an emergency decryption code to use when I forgot my password.

For some reason, when I changed my account password while the drive was being encrypted it gave me another emergency code. How can I verify which one works?

Comment: My question was solved by http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56059/how-can-i-verify-a-lion-filevault-recovery-key?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Can restart the computer in recovery mode (Cmd-R, while starting up).   Go to Disk utility.   Encrypted disk will be greyed out.   Right click (option- click) to unlock it.   See which of your codes work.

Comment: Neither code worked, however my account password was able to decrypt the disk. However there is a possibility that I mistook a letter for a number; I'll try it again today

Comment: if neither works probably safer to turn file vault of and on again to get new code.   I always copy and past these codes.   It is the code in the XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX format?

Comment: Yeah, my code is in that XXXX-* format. I also entered in the dashes into Disk Utility; not sure if I was supposed to or not.